# Create a tree data structure faster for creating a interactive treemap using highcharter

Tags: r, hierarchy, treemap

**Objective:** To transform data to a tree data structure with custom aggregated values in different hierarchy levels to feed in as input to `highcharter` package for r, to create a interactive `treemap`

I have created the tree manually using `data.tree` package as it helps with easier manipulation. Here is the code

data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Costcenter = c("N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", 
"N1", "N1", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N3", "N3", "N4", 
"N5", "N5", "N6"), Vendor = c("L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", 
"L2", "L2", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L2", "L2", "L2", 
"L2", "L2", "L2"), absDiff = c(103.0776, 37.9086, 269.7629, 6.0888, 
515.388, 27.2604, 27.2604, 6.3608, 4.5434, 88.5966, 982.2193, 
139.4249, 0.5452, 722.9811, 130.3381, 147.8434, 271.8786, 88.5966, 
327.4065, 366.564), value = c(103.0776, 37.9086, 269.7629, 6.0888, 
515.388, 27.2604, 27.2604, 6.3608, 4.5434, 88.5966, 982.2193, 
139.4249, 0.5452, 722.9811, 130.3381, 147.8434, 271.8786, 88.5966, 
327.4065, 366.564), Tool = c("M1", "M2", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M9", 
"M10", "M11", "M8", "M5", "M9", "M10", "M3", "M7", "M4", "M5", 
"M5", "M5", "M10", "M5")), .Names = c("Costcenter", "Vendor", 
"absDiff", "value", "Tool"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code

```
    #specify the tree hierarchy
df$pathString <- paste("Root" ,df$Costcenter, df$Vendor, df$Tool,   sep = "/")

library("data.tree")
s <- as.Node(df ,mode="table") #<-performance problem

#create values for parent nodes, by aggregation of children values
s$Do(function(node) node$value <- Aggregate(node , attribute = "value", aggFun = sum), traversal = "post-order")

# assign ids to all nodes
s$Set(id = 1:s$totalCount)
# calculate parent ids for all children, using parent1 as parent is system reserved by data.tree
s$Set(parent1 = c(function(self) GetAttribute(self$parent, "id", format = identity)))

#copy the data tree structure to a data.frame
test <- ToDataFrameTree(s,"value", "level", "id","parent1")#<-performance problem

test <- data.table(test)
test[,parent:= as.character(parent1)] # parent and ids should be of character for highcharts
test[,id:=as.character(id)] # parent and ids should be of character for highcharts

test[,value:= as.numeric(trimws(value))]

library(rCharts)
#convert each row to a list
list <- toJSONArray2(test,FALSE)


library(highcharter)
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(
    type = "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
    allowDrillToNode = TRUE,
    levels = list(
      list(
        level = 1,
        dataLabels = list(
          enabled = TRUE
        ),
        borderWidth = 3
      ),
      list(
        level = 2,
        dataLabels = list(
          enabled = TRUE
        ),
        borderWidth = 2
      )
    ),
    data= list
  )
```

This code works fine for smaller data sets. However when my data goes into 100s of nodes, the runtime goes upto 70 seconds. I have pinpointed the area of concern to `as.node()` and `ToDataFrameTree()` functions. Please help me to bring down the runtime. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks ok. Also, data.tree should work rather fast for thousands of rows. If you can send me the data (to the email specified as the package maintainer), I can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, I have emailed the anonimized data. For clarification - I have around 6k rows. Thanks in advance :)